# address_picker-rails gem removes styling

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

When i include , //= require address_picker-rails in my application.js file it seems to remove the stylings of other jquery objects, like my date-picker. It has a transparent background for one.

I'm not really up to speed with jquery so is there anywhere where it might be resetting the CSS that i should look?

Answer (score 0):

Move it above/below the other //jquery objects